# forward/backward/next/previous element against YAML?

Tags: cursor, navigation

The lisp program is structured language, and one can execute <kbd>`C-M-f`</kbd>(`forward-sexp`) to pick the next sibling element.  Similarly, <kbd>C-M-b</kbd>, <kbd>C-M-u</kbd>, <kbd>C-M-d</kbd> are defined; they can be used to move the cursor to backward/upward/down the current lisp element.

Nowadays, there are many occasions to edit YAML files.  Since YAML file is also a structured language, I thought it would be nice if we could similar operation for moving around, against these files.

#### Question

When editing YAML files, can I move the cursor according to the current YAML element being pointed by the cursor, just like we'd go up/down/next/previous element in the lisp snippet?

Answer (score 1):

This would be a feature of the major mode you use.  AFAICT, the only `yaml-mode` I can find does not offer such functionality, sadly.  Maybe [indent-tools](https://gitlab.com/emacs-stuff/indent-tools/) provides what you're looking for?